# Cyclic import error

Tags: python, django, import, python-import

Whatever I try to import from my `pupils` app, I get an import error. For example:

**offices/models.py**

```
from pupils.models import Pupils  # => ImportError: cannot import name Pupils
```

I bet the path is right, PyCharm reads it. Everything imports fine from another apps by the way.

Comment: Try relative import `from .models import Pupils`

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev it won't work because I'm trying to Import my model in another app.

Comment: Could you be running into a circular import issue? Is there code in `pupils.models` that is trying to import from this file?

Comment: @solarissmoke yes. What is the solution in this problem?

Comment: Move your import into the method that uses it, instead of at the top of the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you meet the `cyclic imports` problem.

An easy way to fix it is import `Pupils` later:

```
def where_you_need_pupils():
    from pupils.models import Pupils
    # do something
```

Comment: Yes. I actually did meet the cyclic imports problem. Did know about it before. Thanks.